# sed remove a numbered content from a pattern

Tags: regex, sed

I have the following pattern

```
<number>5645646546545656756756757</number>
```

I am trying to remove the number but could not make it work.

```
sed 's/.*<number>[0-9]<\/number>.*/replace/g' xml.log
```

Comment: Im not sure about sed but shouldnt the pattern [0-9] be [0-9]+ ?

Comment: sed historically uses BREs not EREs so it will understand [0-9]* but not [0-9]+. You need [0-9][0-9]* in sed to portably mimic [0-9]+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to remove the tags and the number:

```
sed 's@<number>[0-9]*</number>@replace@g' xml.log
```

If you want to remove the number:

```
sed 's@<number>[0-9]*</number>@<number></number>@g' xml.log
```

If you want to make in-place substitution (in file), add `-i`:

```
sed -i 's@<number>[0-9]*</number>@replace@g' xml.log
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the answer.

Comment: Consider `sed 's@\(<number>\)[0-9]*\(</number\)>@\1\2@g' xml.log` so you don't need to duplicate your tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
echo '<number>5645646546545656756756757</number>' | sed 's/.*<number>\([0-9]*\)<\/number>.*/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove numbers or whatever the characters inside the tag you can use the following. So it's not considering only the <number> and </number> as a tag.

```
sed 's@\(<[^>]*>\)[^<]*\(<[^>]*>\)@\1\2@g'
```

remove g in the last if pattern occurs once in a line.